# Chernoff Type Bounds for Uniformly Bounded Conditional Random Variables

Tags: probability, independence, upper-lower-bounds

I am considering a set of Bernoulli RVs $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ for which we have a uniform conditional bound $\mathbb{P}[X_i=1|X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1}]  \leq p$ for fixed $p$. Can we show the sum of these random variables is no larger than a the sum of i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ with parameter $p$?

In other words, for any $C$ can we show
$\mathbb{P}[\sum X_i > C] \leq \mathbb{P}[\sum Y_i > C]$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes we can. Define $p_k(X_{1,\dots,k-1}) := \mathbb{P}(X_k=1|X_1,\dots,X_{k-1}) \leq p$. Here $p_1$ is just a constant. Notice that the joint distribution of $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is uniquely characterized by the sequence of functions $\{p_k\}_{k=1}^n$ (This is clearly true for $n=1$. For other cases, just use induction).

Let $\{U_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of i.i.d. uniform$[0,1]$ random variables. Let $\overline{X}_k = \mathbb{I}_{U_k < p_k(\overline{X}_{1,\dots,k-1})}$. Then for any $n$, $(\overline{X}_1,\dots,\overline{X}_n) \overset{(d)}{=} (X_1,\dots,X_n)$.

Let $Y_k = \mathbb{I}_{U_k < p}$. Then $\{Y_k\}$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p$ and $Y_k \geq \overline{X}_k$ almost surely. So for any $C$, $\sum_{k=1}^n \overline{X}_k > C$ implies $\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k > C$. By monotonicity of probability measures,

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n X_n > C\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \overline{X}_n > C\right) \leq \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k > C\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment! The transformation involved was very nice. The underlying conditions of my problem can also be stated as a bound on successive terms |X_t - X_{t-1}|, for which I discovered the Azuma-Hoeffding inequality.

Comment: It seems to me that the $\overline{X}_k$ are all independent. So, I don't understand why we the equality in distribution above should be true because that would imply that the $X_k$ are independent as well...

Comment: Use induction to prove equality in distribution. Define $Y^{k-1} := Y_{1,\dots,k-1}$ for any process $Y$. $X_1$ and $\overline{X}_1$ are Bernoulli with the same parameter. Apply induction:

$$\mathbb{P}(\overline{X}_k=1,\overline{X}^{k-1} = x) = \mathbb{P}(\overline{X}_k=1|\overline{X}^{k-1} = x)\mathbb{P}(\overline{X}^{k-1} = x) = \mathbb{P}(U_k < p_k(\overline{X}^{k-1})|\overline{X}^{k-1}=x) \mathbb{P}(X^{k-1} = x)  = p_k(x)\mathbb{P}(X^{k-1} = x) =  \mathbb{P}(X_k=1|X^{k-1} = x)\mathbb{P}(X^{k-1} = x) = \mathbb{P}(X_k=1,X^{k-1} = x)$$

The $\overline{X}_k = 0$ case is similar.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. Here is the argument I found.

Let $\Omega$ be the set of all binary sequences
of length $n$ with at least $C$ ones.
For $x \in \Omega$, let $Pr_{1}(x)$  denote the probability of $x$ occurring as a result
of the trials $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$.
Suppose the last Bernoulli trial $X_n$ is
replaced with an independent Bernoulli trial
$Y_n$ with success probability $p$ --
denote the resulting probability of a sequence $x$
as $Pr_{2}(x)$.
Any sequence in $\Omega$ whose probability decreases
as a result of the change must end in a $0$.
Let $x0 \in \Omega$; then it also holds that $x1$ is in $\Omega$. Further,
$$ Pr_2( x1 ) + Pr_2( x0 ) = Pr_2(x) = Pr_1(x) = Pr_1(x1) + Pr_1(x0). $$
Therefore, $Pr_2( \Omega ) \ge Pr_1( \Omega )$.
Continue this argument inductively to replace
$X_{n-1}, X_{n-2}, \ldots X_1$ with independent
Bernoulli variables $Y_{n-1}, \ldots, Y_1$ to
obtain probability distributions $Pr_i$ such
that $Pr_{i+1}( \Omega ) \ge Pr_i(\Omega)$.
Finally,

\begin{align*}                                                                                                
    Pr \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i \ge C \right) 
    &\ge Pr \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i \ge C \right).                                                              
  \end{align*}